# Square wave oscillator

Tags: signal, frequency, oscillation

I built a square wave generator using an astable multivibrator circuit. With

- RB1 = RB2 = 100 kΩ
- C1 = C2 = 1 μ
- F my frequency is approximately 7.14 Hz.

Is there any possibility to improve my circuit by just using passive and active components or changing the values of the existing components to obtain a frequency band between 26 kHz and 52 kHz for a load resistance of 13 kΩ?

[image]

Comment: There is a possibility, yes. Maybe you should ask for solutions how to do it?

Comment: Are you searching "how" to make a VCO?

Comment: Im trying to make a square signal generator using just discrete components, with adjustable peak to peak oscillation voltage, adjustable frequency

Comment: VCO is "voltage controlled oscillator".

Comment: Adjustable peak to peak voltage can be done with a potentiometer and a "voltage" follower made with another BJT.

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ to tell us what your goals really are.  My "improvement" might be your "hey, you screwed it up!", and visa-versa.  It sounds like you want adjustable frequency and amplitude -- you should state that in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the frequency of oscillation by changing the capacitor value. This LTSPICE simulation results in a frequency in the range of 32kHz.

[image]

Comment: For [x_val, y_val] Khz frequency, is it possible to set the value of frequency by using a potentiometer for variable resistance of R2, R3 ?

Comment: I dont see why no.